# Вывод новых сообщений выше старых mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Примером может послужить ВК диалоги.
Делаю запрос в базу сообщений, где данные группируются по ID пользователя.
Данные выводятся старые, то есть дата в группе пользователя та, что присвоена самому первому сообщению отправленному ему.
К примеру диалог 1. 17 июня, 2. 18 июня и т д. Выводит ту, что с 17 июня, а нужно выводить новые, после 18 июня.
**Сам запрос**:
`SELECT * FROM chat WHERE dialog IN ($dialog_value) GROUP BY users ORDER BY date DESC`
Идея такова, чтобы диалоги выводились новые выше старых и еще выше те, что со значением status = 1.
**Структура таблицы chat**:
id, dialog ( ИД общей конференции ), text ( Тест сообщения ),users ( ИД пользователя отправившего сообщение ), date, status ( Статус доставки сообщения ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При группировке MySQL для колонок не входящих в group by берет первое значение для группы, а вам надо брать максимальное. И вместо '*' возможно стоит выбирать только единственную колонку users, ибо значениями остальных пользоваться все равно нельзя ибо они опять же первые попавшиеся для группы.

```
SELECT *,max(date) maxdt,max(status) maxst
  FROM chat
 WHERE dialog IN ($dialog_value)
 GROUP BY users
 ORDER BY maxst DESC, maxdt DESC
```